# Saving a rasterisation of a canvas element, server side

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, server-side, raphael

I've built a page which uses some jQuery, and [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) (vectors and images on canvas), to allow a user to customise a picture by choosing a few colors. The whole canvas can be recreated on the client side by being initialized with an array of simple arguments like:

```
  initCanvas({
    'wall' : 'green',
    'ceiling' : 'black',
    'floor' : 'white'
  })
```

So anything a user created could be recreated easily.

Is it possible get the server to render and save this canvas as an image?

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Does it need to be saved on the server? If not, the canvas's `toDataURL` method could do it (as e.g. [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) does). If, however, you're wanting e.g. image thumbnailing for the server, that wouldn't cut it.

Comment: Why did you put this as a comment when it would be better as an answer?

Comment: @graham.reeds: because it's not an answer - he asked for a server implementation, but I'm suggesting a client implementation which probably isn't what he wants, and asking for a clarification of whether it does *need* to be on the server. If he said client was OK I'd put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though this would be a good solution to your problem: http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/06/04/export-svg-from-raphael-js-to-create-a-png-bitmap/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reconstructed the svg server-side and Batik did a great job of rasterizing it.

Answer (score 1):

The guys from LearnBoost has a canvas implementation for NodeJS.

http://www.learnboost.com/introducing-node-canvas-server-side-html5-canvas-api/

Using nodejs and node-canvas you can generate the image using canvas on the server side and stream it back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

First send it to the server via JSON.

Once there you can go two routes.

1. Render it via Batik
   (easy if you have a java server but
   becomes painful if running php) or
2. Send it to ImageMagik.